# Copy Row From Sheet A and append it in Sheet B in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have sheet A which contains few rows, when clicking on the Checkbox it should copy in Sheet B..

Sheet A

[image]

When I select a checkbox, I want that record to copy in sheet B and also remain in SheetA
with only ID and Name

Here is my code that I wrote

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if (s.getName() == "SheetA" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn() - 1;
    var targetSheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("SheetB");
    var target1 = targetSheet1.getRange(targetSheet1.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target1);
    Browser.msgBox("Your Record Submitted");
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the checkbox at the column "H" in "SheetA" is checked, you want to copy the values (columns "A" to "G") of the same row with the checkbox to the next row of the last row of "SheetB" using the simple trigger with Google Apps Script.
- When the values are copied, you want to leave the values of columns "A" and "B".

#### Modification points:

- In your script, by `s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target1);`, the all values of the row are moved. By this, the values of columns "A" and "B" are also removed. And also, by `s.deleteRow(row);`, the row is deleted.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (s.getName() == "SheetA" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() === true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn()-1;
    var targetSheet1 = event.source.getSheetByName("SheetB");
    var target1 = targetSheet1.getRange(targetSheet1.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    
    // I modified below script.
    var range = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
    if (!range.getValues()[0].every(e => e.toString() == "")) {  // Added
      range.copyTo(target1);
      range.offset(0, 2, 1, 5).clearContent();
      range.offset(0, 7).uncheck();
      Browser.msgBox("Your Record Submitted");
    }
  } 
}
```

- When you use this script, please check the checkbox at the column "H" in "SheetA". By this, the script is run. When the script is run, the values of columns "A" to "G" are copied to "SheetB" and the values of columns "C" to "G" are cleared. And also, the checkbox is unchecked. By this, the values of columns "A" and "B" are not removed.
- When `range.offset(0, 2, 1, 6).clearContent();` is used, `range.offset(0, 7).uncheck();` is not required to be used. But in this case, the value of checkbox is also removed. So in this modification, I used `uncheck()`. By this, the value of checkbox is changed to `FALSE`.

#### References:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent())
- [uncheck()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck)

Comment: How can I add a condition there if A to G is blank if blank do not copy in sheet B?

Comment: @Abhishek Vaidya Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `How can I add a condition there if A to G is blank if blank do not copy in sheet B?`, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: It is not working I am able to insert even it A to G is blank

Comment: @Abhishek Vaidya Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `How can I add a condition there if A to G is blank if blank do not copy in sheet B?`, in this case, when the values of columns "A" to "G" are empty, you don't want to copy the values. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your understanding is very Correct. IF any fields from A to G is blank don't copy that row in Sheet B

Comment: @Abhishek Vaidya Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, my updated script is for it. So I cannot replicate your issue. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your 2nd question, I'm glad.

Comment: @Abhishek Vaidya Or, when `if (!range.getValues()[0].every(e => e.toString() == "")) {` is modified to `if (!range.offset(0, 0, 1, 7).getValues()[0].every(e => e.toString() == "")) {`, what result will you get?

Comment: @Abhishek Vaidya Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `It is not working`, I cannot understand about the detail of your situation. And, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because in my environment, I could confirm that the modified script worked. I apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including more information for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your 2nd question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your 2nd question?

Comment: Sure Adding a new  question

Comment: @Abhishek Vaidya Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm it when I saw your new question. I deeply apologize that your 2nd question cannot be resolved soon. This is due to my poor skill. I would like to study more.

Comment: Not Like that @Tanaike, I can see your expert Thankful for your words

Comment: Hi,I have posted a new question please have look link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331633/copy-row-to-another-sheet-only-if-all-values-are-filled

Comment: @Abhishek Vaidya Thank you for your response. I would like to check it.