# Copy row to another sheet only if all values are filled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]Thanks for your time.
My questions are as follow:

My SheetA (Record) contains rows, when I click on the Checkbox, it should check if all cells A-G contains some value,
If any cell from the A-G is blank, do not copy tat in SheetB and show msgbox

I also want to implement if Column A contains some value then only Show Dropdown at Column H and Checkbox at column G

Below is my code snippet

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (s.getName() == "Record" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() === true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn() - 1;
    var targetSheet1 = event.source.getSheetByName("Master Record Time");
    var target1 = targetSheet1.getRange(targetSheet1.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    var range = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
    if (!range.offset(0, 0, 1, 7).getValues()[0].every(e => e.toString() == "")) { // Added
      range.copyTo(target1);
      range.offset(0, 2, 1, 5).clearContent();
      range.offset(0, 7).uncheck();
      Browser.msgBox("Your Record Submitted");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this script, I think that when the values of columns "A" to "G" of "Record" are empty, the script in the if statement is not run. So I think that in this case, it is required to now the situation of Spreadsheet. If you can do, please add an image of the sample Spreadsheet? How about this?

Comment: Please check I have added the Image for your ref

Comment: Thank you for replying adding more information. In your case, when the checkbox of "H5" is checked, what result will you get?

Comment: Ohh it won't  be able to add that to next sheet Your code was correct actually Bad in my requirement. My requirement is like any of the cell is blank it should not add

Comment: My Requirement is if any of the cell is blank it should throw lets say A,b,c,d columns are filled but remaining are empty in such case it should not add to another sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, you don't want to copy the row when one of values of columns "A" to "G" is empty. If my understanding is correct, please modify `if (!range.offset(0, 0, 1, 7).getValues()[0].every(e => e.toString() == "")) {` to `if (!range.offset(0, 0, 1, 7).getValues()[0].some(e => e.toString() == "")) {`, and test it again.

Comment: Thats Perfect It is working Fine

Comment: I learned a lot while implementing this, Thank you very much

Comment: Can you help me with my second question?I also want to implement if Column A contains some value then only Show Dropdown at Column H and Checkbox at column G

Comment: for sure I will mark it as resolved

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, about `I also want to implement if Column A contains some value then only Show Dropdown at Column H and Checkbox at column G`, I cannot understand this situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can you provide the detail information about your 2nd question?

Comment: Could be my problem...Sure So what I want is When there is something in Column A, then only Column G and H should be visible otherwise if there is nothing in that col, if you check 5th row column A there is nothing still dropdown and checkbox is visible I want that to be disable

Comment: Ask follow up questions in a new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

You only want to copy the range if none of the cells are blank.

#### Current issue:

Right now, you are checking whether `every` cell is blank, and entering the `if` statement if that's not the case:

```
!range.offset(0, 0, 1, 7).getValues()[0].every(e => e.toString() == "")
```

That is to say, it will enter the `if` statement if there's any non-blank cell, even if there are also blank cells.

#### Possible modifications:

As suggested by [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331633/copy-row-to-another-sheet-only-if-all-values-are-filled/64333941#comment113758030_64331633), you should change that condition to the following:

```
!range.offset(0, 0, 1, 7).getValues()[0].some(e => e.toString() == "")
```

Or, alternatively, to:

```
range.offset(0, 0, 1, 7).getValues()[0].every(e => e.toString() != "")
```

#### Reference:

- [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)